# How to make a change on all pages with a specific URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list or URLs that I need to add a body class to. The list of URLs are found in the queryStrings variable. Here is my current code:

```
    var myUrl = window.location.href;
    var queryStrings = ["www.site.com/test", "www.site.com/test2"];
    var allPresent = CheckIfAllQueryStringsExist(myUrl, queryStrings);

    if (allPresent == false) {

    } else {
        document.body.classList.add("module-ads");
    }

    function CheckIfAllQueryStringsExist(url, qsCollection) {
        for (var i = 0; i < qsCollection.length; i++) {
            if (url.indexOf(qsCollection[i]) == -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Right now, allPresent equals false even if I am on the page www.site.com/test.

Comment: Is this a web extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are checking the URL to see if it contains the array, which is backward.

Also, you don't need any loops here. Just check the array for the existence of the current URL and instead of an empty `true` branch to your first `if` statement, just reverse the test logic so that you can just have one branch.

```
var myUrl = window.location.href;
var queryStrings = ["www.site.com/test", "www.site.com/test2"];
var allPresent = CheckIfAllQueryStringsExist(myUrl, queryStrings);

if (allPresent) {
    document.body.classList.add("module-ads");
}

function CheckIfAllQueryStringsExist(url, qsCollection) {
  // Just return whether the array contains the url
  return qsCollection.indexOf(url) > -1;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP whats to check if the url contains any of the strings in the array not if it matches them exactly.

Comment: @Titus That's not at all how I read it. --> *I have a list or URLs that I need to add a body class to.* So, the array of URLs needs to be checked to see if the current URL exists within it so that the class can be applied.

Answer (score 2):

Your **CheckIfAllQueryStringsExist** is wrong.

Change it to:

```
function CheckIfAllQueryStringsExist(url, qsCollection) {
    for (var i = 0; i < qsCollection.length; i++) {
        if (url.indexOf(qsCollection[i]) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the window.location object, that will give you many other ways to match your url.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

href will return the protocol, so you could just tack on "https://" + to each href check, or you could use location.pathname or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array function `.includes()`  to do your check. Otherwise, @gaetanoM answer is the answer you're looking for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

```js
var myUrl = window.location.href;
var queryStrings = ["www.site.com/test", "www.site.com/test2"];
var allPresent = queryStrings.includes(myUrl);

if (allPresent == false) {
  // do something
} else {
  document.body.classList.add("module-ads");
}
```